# How to find position of result in couchbase query?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am looking for a way to find the position of the first document (given some kind of criteria like `userId="user123"`) for an ordered N1QL query, so something like this:

```
SELECT ARRAY_POSITION(allPoints, "user123")
LET allPoints = (SELECT userId from stuff WHERE ... ORDER BY points DESC, userId ASC)
```

However, it doesn't work since the subquery "allPoints" returns an array of *objects* (each having just one attribute which is 'userId')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution 2 minutes after posting :)

I was pretty close, it works like this:

```
SELECT ARRAY_POSITION(allPoints, {"userId":"user123"})
LET allPoints = (SELECT userId from stuff WHERE ... ORDER BY points DESC, userId ASC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following expression to find position in points array  when lang 10.0 and lat 20.1 (WHEN clause can have any type of condition)

```
(FIRST pos FOR pos:v IN points WHEN v.lang = 10.0 AND v.lat = 20.1 END)
```